# RadioButton and switch

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement

I have many radio buttons so I end up with code that look like this

```
if (rbFrenchImp.Checked)
{
}
else if (rbFrenchMet.Checked)
{
}
else if (rbEnglishImp.Checked)
{
}
else if (rbFrenchEuro.Checked)
{
}
//etc...
```

So I was wondering, is it possible to use a switch case with radio button? If yes how?

Comment: Is it WinForms, WPF, or WebForms?

Comment: are you using webforms? if so, why not use a `RadioButtonList`?

Comment: @Mr. TA: Does it matter? This is not a question about radio buttons, it's about `switch` with multiple boolean statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can:

You subcribe the same CheckChanged(or similar) event handler to each of the radio buttons. Then you put some code like this:

```
RadioButton btn = sender as RadioButton;
if(btn!= null && btn.IsChecked)
{
   Switch(btn.Name)
   {
      case "rbFrenchImpl":
      break;
      ...
   }
}
```

This works on all type of frameworks.

Comment: Dang. That leaves us with hard-coding the radio-button name.

Comment: 2017 Checking in - you can use nameof(rbFrenchImpl) in a case now!

Answer (score 4):

Feels slightly hacky, but you could set up a `Dictionary<RadioButton, Action>` containing a mapping between `RadioButton` controls and corresponding methods (that are parameterless `void` methods, matching the `Action` delegate signature):

```
Dictionary<RadioButton, Action> _rbMethods = new Dictionary<RadioButton, Action>();
```

When loading the form, add the buttons and corresponding methods to the map:

```
_rbMethods.Add(rbFrenchImp, FrenchImpAction);
_rbMethods.Add(rbFrenchMet, FrenchMetAction);
_rbMethods.Add(rbEnglishImp, EnglishImpAction);
```

Then, you can quite easily invoke corresponding methods for the checked radio button (or buttons, in case they are in different groups):

```
foreach (RadioButton key in _rbMethods.Keys.Where(rb => rb.Checked))
{
    _rbMethods[key]();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best method I found for changing an "if statement" with multiple radio buttons into a case switch.  All you need to do with the radio button is select the event tab under properties and select radioButton_Click under the "Checked" event.  I hope this will be helpful to someone in the future.

```
private void radioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton radioBtn = (RadioButton)sender;
            if (radioBtn.IsChecked == true)
            {
                switch (radioBtn.Name)
                {
                    case "radioBtnName1":
                        //do something
                        break;

                    case "radioBtnName2":
                        //do something
                        break;

                    case "radioBtnName3":
                        //do something
                        break;

                    case "radioBtnName4":
                        //do something
                        break;
                }

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a `RadioButtonList`? If so, you can just look for `.SelectedValue`.

Otherwise, if you've just got a selection of radio buttons, you're only option will be to, yes, loop over them in some fashion. I'd guess, however, that you can probably replace the scheme you have with a [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) to achieve some sort of success.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using ASP.NET you can use [radiobuttonlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) and switch like in this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Asp-Control/UseSwitchtoreadRadioButtonChoiceC.htm)  dont´t know about windows form or wpf

Answer (score 0):

```
//create a global radioCheckStatus
RadioCheckStatus radioStatus = RadioCheckStatus.none;

//declare your enum
private enum RadioCheckStatus
{
      none = 0,
      rbFrenchImp = 1,
      rbFrenchMet = 2,
      rbEnglishImp = 3,
      rbFrenchEuro = 4
}

//On CheckedChanged event of your radioButtons set it to changed radioButtons enum
private void rbFrenchImp_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      radioStatus = RadioCheckStatus.rbFrenchImp;
}

// whereever you want to check the selected value
switch (radioStatus)
{
      case RadioCheckStatus.rbFrenchImp:
      {
             break;
      }
      case RadioCheckStatus.rbFrenchEuro:
      {
             break;
      }
      case RadioCheckStatus.rbEnglishImp:
      {
             break;
      }
      case RadioCheckStatus.rbFrenchMet:
      {
             break;
      }
      default:
             break;
}
```

Comment: It is too complicated, you have to define a new CheckChanged handler for each radio button. Declare enums and so on...

Comment: I wouldn't use switch if the radiobuttons don't already have an eventHandler. OP asked for a way to replace the if - else if with switch case and only way is this if that control is being made in the eventhandler of another control (your solution also wouldn't work).

Comment: Why is this better than the original solution?

Comment: @Cody Readability is the only reason I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Solution using Linq:

```
var rbResult = from rb in gbState.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>() 
where rb.Checked 
select rb;
```

This will give you a `<IENumerable>RadioButton`.
As your Radiobuttons should be in a Container like a GroupBox, this IENumberable can contain only 1 or 0 elements.

I think this should work. If it does not, please correct me

Answer (score 0):

In each RadionButton properties set actionCommand a value (1, 2, 3...) then get the name of the Button Group:

```
switch(Integer.parseInt(buttonGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand()))
    {
    case 1:
         do something...
         break;
    case 2:
         do somenthing...
         break;
    case 3:
         do somenthing...
         break;
    default:
  
    }
```